# Connect to Access database in Azure website

Tags: database, azure, asp-classic, migrate

I have a website running on server 2012 r2 with an access .mdb database.

I have a connection to the database with the following code. This was not coded by myself

' Connection Strings
    dim Conn
    ' Add full path of database with filename here
    cnProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;"
    cnDataSource = "Data Source =C:\websites\client\database\aspProductCatalog.mdb"
    Conn = cnProvider & cnDataSource

I used the azure website migration tool to migrate this site to azure websites just hosted on a basic azure websites plan.

once everything was upload i ftp into the website and change the above code to

' Connection Strings
    dim Conn
    ' Add full path of database with filename here
    cnProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;"
    cnDataSource = "Data Source =/site/wwwroot/database\aspProductCatalog.mdb"
    Conn = cnProvider & cnDataSource

but no luck so i assume i have to create a connection string within azure websites but have had no luck with that yet either. The two strings i have tried so far are as follows

conn.open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.Mappath("/site/wwwroot/database/aspProductCatalog.mdb")
**I set the type of this string to custom**

and

conn.open "driver={Mic0rosoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};dbq=/site/wwwroot/database/aspProductCatalog.mdb;"
**I set the type of this string to custom**

the error i get when browsing the catalogue page that displays uses the database is
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

hopefully this makes more sense to people

Comment: Please make the question clear

Comment: My question is simple. How do i setup a connecting to a .mdb database in azure?

Comment: Do you have an error / exception message to show us?

Comment: Please **edit your question** with more details, such as: Where did you install the app (VM? Azure Websites?)? How did you install Access (to a VM?)? Is your app scaled to multiple instances? Etc. And please don't put extra details in comments.